# How change default :( Oops Internal Server Error 500 в .Net Core?

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

Sometimes appears in .Net Core project. No in IIS and no in project. Can't find where i can change it.
[image]

Comment: Sounds like reading about [error handling in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling) would be handy.

Comment: Can you elaborate on your question? Sample code, what line in the source code the error is occurring? Are you running this from VS or VS Code?

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/issues/717 you have to follow the troubleshooting steps described in this thread.

Answer (score 0):

Navigate to web.config file which is placed in the directory to which you've published your application. It should looks as fallow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified" />
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\YOUR.APPLICATION.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false" />
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Look for `stdoutLogEnabled` and `stdoutLogFile`. Set the first one to true and you will be able to look what is going on in the log files.

TIP: Create directory `logs` in your application (on the same level where web.config file is located) and assign full rights to Everyone.

**UPDATE:** To change default error page with customized one you can use something like that:

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
    <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="13" /> //subStatusCode just if needed
    <error statusCode="500"
           subStatusCode="13"
           prefixLanguageFilePath=""
           path="http://YOUR_SITE.com/path/to/page"
           responseMode="Redirect" />
  </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Assigning Full Control to Everyone generally is bad advice, and the question here is not how to log, but how to change the default error page.

Comment: Of course it is bad idea - it was just a tip to skip issues with rights to quickly get log files been created. I've updated my answer with additional information how to customize error page.